# visual basic 2012 connection must be valid and open

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What I have is a small messaging function that basically can send a message to one user or to a group of users. There are two mysql tables; one called users for the users who use the system, and another messages where the messages are stored. The system can send to specific users but when sending to  a group of people, VB gives me the

> InvalidOperationException was handled: connection should be open and valid

The code is given below.

```
Dim receiver, subject, message As String
Dim user As Integer
Dim MySqlConnection As New MySqlConnection
Dim MyAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim command As New MySqlCommand
Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
Private Sub sendButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sendButton.Click

user = loginForm.user
If recieverTextBox.Text = "" And studentCheckBox.Checked = False And facultyCheckBox.Checked = True Then

        subject = subjectTextBox.Text
        message = messageRichTextBox.Text
        MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; User ID=root; password=''; database=sis_db"
        Dim query = "insert into messages (date, sender, receiver, subject, message) select CURRENT_DATE, '" & user & "',user_id,'" & subject & "', '" & message & "' from users where user_type='faculty';"

        Try
            MySqlConnection.Open()
            command.CommandText = query
            MyAdapter.SelectCommand = command
            mydata = command.ExecuteReader 'the error message points here'
            MsgBox("Messages sent", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, Title:="SUCCESS!")
            recieverTextBox.Clear()
            subjectTextBox.Clear()
            messageRichTextBox.Clear()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox("DATABASE ERROR!")
        End Try

        MySqlConnection.Close()

    ElseIf
```

Comment: Please put the entire code. Which row is giving the error? Stacktrace also? It seems to me your connectino has been closed after using and then trying to use a closed connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace the select current_date with `DateTime.Now` instead

have you tested the connection ? its probably just a typo